# Link between RF433 emitter and antenna

Tags: rf, antenna

I am looking for a way to link a [RF433 emitter](http://www.gotronic.fr/pj-397.pdf)

[image: RF433 emitter]

to a [RF433 antenna](http://datasheetz.com/data/RF%20and%20RFID/RF%20Antennas/ANT-433-CW-HW-datasheetz.html)

[image: RF433 antenna]

Since there is an "ANT" pin on the emitter I assume I can connect an antenna to it.

However, I do not know how to do this kind of link. I had a look on the Internet, and I saw that some people recommend using coaxial links. Do you have any explanation to share with me?

Comment: 1) Are you familiar with RF circuit design ? 2) What is the exact reference of your component ?

Comment: Do whatever it says to do in the datasheet.  Closing since we're not here to read the datasheet to you, which you haven't even bothered to link to.  It's unreasonable to expect us to know what this "RF433" device is.

Comment: @OlinLathrop RF433 is a generic name for a blackbox arduino module : http://www.seeedstudio.com/wiki/433Mhz_RF_link_kit As a young student not very proficient in electronics he might have thought that "rf433" was a proper denomination.

Comment: @MaximGi, here are the 2 components (references are on a French site, that is where I buy my components): http://www.gotronic.fr/art-emetteur-am-tx433-3715.htm (the sender), and http://www.gotronic.fr/art-antenne-coudee-433-mhz-ant433c-8499.htm (the antenna). If you need any translations, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: @OlinLathrop I am sorry to have not gave that reference in my first message. I tried, but as I do not have a good enough reputation, I could only give two links (beside images). I prefered gave image, as I though it would be more helpful for you. Next time, I will give direct link as the one I gave in my previous message. Also, as I told, I had look on the Internet, but I could not find any _good_ explanation about how to link components together (except the fact I may need coaxial cable). I have not bought yet the antenna. If the one I shown is not good, I could choose another one.

Comment: @MaximGi, what do you mean by familiar? For now, I only plugged a sender to an Arduino, a receiver to another one, and making them communicating.

Comment: @Loic You need to check to see which connector is already on the antenna, then buy a same-connector socket to solder to your PCB or case. The "ant" pin is the signal to the center of the connector, and the outside of the connector should connect to "gnd" on your transmitter/receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an antenna pin on the transmitter module and an [RP-SMA connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMA_connector#Reverse_polarity_SMA) attached to the antenna.

The usual way to connect these is to use an [RP-SMA pigtail](https://www.google.de/search?q=rp-sma+pigtail+solder). That's a coaxial cable with a matching connector on one end.

The solderable end of the pigtail's coaxial cable goes across pin 4 (antenna) and pin 1 (ground). Other modules might differ, always refer to the data sheet of the respective transmitter you end up buying.

If you shop for a matching cable, keep in mind that – since your antenna has an internal thread and a pin – the pigtail's complementary RP-SMA connector must feature an external thread and a hole.

Comment: You mention the "RP-SMA pigtail". Is it a ready-to-use cable, or am I missing something?

Comment: You need a soldering iron. But that's the case anyway. ;)

Comment: Oh, and I didn't just *mention* the pigtail. There are links in my answer that take you to further explanations and products. I could't find the matching pigtail in the shop you use, but that's probably just because I don't speak french.

Comment: Yes, you gave me links, I saw them ;) I am sorry if I did not use the right word for this, I am a French guy, and sometimes, I did not use right English words for right things. I had look in the shop, but I could not find one. I have contacted them to check if they have either the component, or something similar. In any case, I think I will go for this solution, which looks quite good to me.

Comment: I didn't mean to come across as rude, sorry if this was the case. ;) Btw., you could start out with a diy style coil antenna and add the external connector at a later time.